# Hover text over post image in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, post, onhover

I've been trying to find a good, simple solution for this for days now, and I'm coming up empty handed.

I'm trying to make a blog in wordpress, that currently has excerpt with images on the front page. The images are not featured images and they link to the full post. What I really want is for "read more" to appear when i hover over the post image on the front page.

Ideally, I would love to implement one of these codrops hover effects (http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/) on the post images if it's possible. I'm very much a newbie to wordpress, so I don't know where to put what code.

But any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below core code of HTML and CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
div.texthover 
{   
    display:block;
    position:relative; 
    width:150px;
}

div.texthover .overlay 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:45%;
    width:100;
    width:150px;       
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display:none;width:150px;
}
div.texthover:hover .overlay 
{
    display:block;
}
</style>


<div class="texthover"><br />
    <img src="image.jpg" width="150" height="150" />
<div class="overlay"><br />
    <span>This is some text I want to display</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do I put the html?

Comment: i just show you example...you need to set css into your own page   according to your requirement and check it.

Comment: Yes, but if I want to set a span class with some text, I would need to place that somewhere? How would I do that in wordpress since it uses php and not html?

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! Something just clicked and I suddenly understood what to do with the code. I guess that's the process of learning. You can spend days and days just looking at something and not getting it, and then suddenly it just makes sense. I understood that I had to find the image in my front-page.php and wrap the html around the image code. I'm so happy now!

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, go to Appearance -> Editor and edit style.css or your main .css theme file. You can put there your hover code. You also need to add the corresponding classes to your image. However if you want "read more" to appear you would need the existing associated HTML code. On another hand, you got some hover plugins available, I found this one with a quick search : https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazing-hover-effects/
Good luck.

Comment: "However if you want "read more" to appear you would need the existing associated HTML code"

By this, do you mean find html in my code, or add some myself? Because it's the html that's my problem. I don't know where to place it or how to use it with the classes i already have.